# Force DISM to unmount/delete a mounted Windows WIM

Tags: windows, mount, dism

I use DISM to customize and update images that I deploy to our computers. I do this on an external drive because its really heavy on I/O. A while ago I appear to have left the image mounted in my F drive as F:\WIN81MOUNT. The files are there. Running `dism /get-mountedwiminfo` however shows that there are no mounted WIMs. As such, I have no idea how to delete WIN81MOUNT as I cannot remount, unmount, or just delete the folder (files have permissions of things like SYSTEM, as they are in the windows image).

How can I force this WIM to unmount, or remount? I have tried all the standard options such as unmount-wim, cleanup-image, remount-wim... none of them work, saying the request is not supported. The log indicates "This is not a WIM mount point.".

Answer (score 2):

Following info is from "http://trueliarx.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/force-unmount-and-clean-up-of-wim-image.html"

> **Force Unmount and Clean up of a Wim Image using DISM**
>
> When you use RT7 (+ AIK) sometimes an error occurs stating that there's a mounted wim (ex.  `boot.wim`).
>
> To solve the problem you should run, as administrator, the command:
>
> ```shellsession
> dism /cleanup-wim
> ```
>
> If it doesn't work I've found another solution by editing the registry and deleting all the (necessary) entries within:
>
> ```
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WIMMount\mounted images\
> ```
>
> It should work as long as you are an administrator.

The regular procedure, which you've already used (?) is shown below:

1. Information can be found in the log file can be found at: `C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log`
2. In the case of 64bit servicing tools previously run on 64bit Windows;

   1. In an elevated command prompt issue;

      ```shellsession
      cd C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Tools\amd64\Servicing
      ```
   2. In the same elevated command prompt issue;

      ```shellsession
      dism /?
      ```

      Some helpful information may be displayed.
   3. In the same elevated command prompt issue;

      ```shellsession
      dism /Get-MountedWimInfo
      ```

      Information about mounted images may be displayed.
   4. If there are any Dirs found to be mounted, which need to be un-mounted, for each Dir issue;

      ```shellsession
      dism /Unmount-Wim /Mountdir:C:\examplepath /commit
      ```

After this is complete the related wim files, found with `Get-MountedWimInfo`, can be deleted using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me as it appeared there was nothing to clean on the dism part, juste the permissions on the folder.

I finally found something working (if the registry and dism solutions listed above don't work) :

> First you must change the owner permissionf of "damaged" mount folder:
>
> Right-Click the folder -> Properties -> Security tab -> Advanced
> button -> Owner tab -> Edit button -> Select your user account ->
> Activate Replace owner on subcontainers and objects.
>
> When done, close all properties windows and open Properties again ->
> Security tab -> Advanced button -> Permissons tab -> Change Permissons
> button -> Add your user account and select Replace all child object...
>
> Then open command promt with administrator priviledges (
> https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
> )
>
> Type the following and press enter:
>
> DISM /Cleanup-Wim Now you should be able to able to delete all
> leftover files/folders.

Source : https://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/12680-cant-delete-wintoolkit_mount-folder/?do=findComment&comment=116249

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort:

1. Open the registry and go at key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WIMMount\Mounted Images.
2. There, you should find one or more subkeys with strange names such as [e86b54b7-dc5f-4c15-8eb5-9b615bc3b154]
3. Open the first of these folders and find out if it corresponds to the mounted image that looks corrupted; use the values [Mount Path], [WIM Path] and [Image Index] to find out.Once you have found the correct subkey mentionned in point 2 above, delete it.
4. Delete and recreate the Mount folder..

Answer (score 0):

Loop through and unmount any left over Wim with PowerShell.

```
$subKeyMatch = "Mount Path"
$orphMountedWims = @()
$regMounted = "REGISTRY::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WIMMount\mounted images"
$mountedKey = [array](Get-ChildItem "$($regMounted)\" -Recurse -Depth 0)
foreach ($key in $mountedKey) {
    $keyProps = ((Get-Item -path "REGISTRY::$key").property)
    foreach ($subKey in $keyProps) {
        if ($subKey -like "$($subKeyMatch)") {
            $regSubPropValue = Get-ItemProperty -path "REGISTRY::$Key" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $subKey 
            $orphMountedWims += $regSubPropValue
        }
    }
}

if (($orphMountedWims | Measure-Object).Count -ge 1) {
    Write-Warning "Orphaned WIM(s) have been found."
    foreach ($oMWim in $orphMountedWims) { 
        try {
            Write-Output "Attempting to dismount and discard changes for Orphaned [Path: $($oMWim)]"
            Dismount-WindowsImage -Path "$($oMWim)"-Discard
            Write-Output "Success discarding changes."
        }
        catch [System.exception] {           
            Write-Error "Error - Failed to dismount and dicard changed from Orphaned wim [Mount Path: $($oMWim)]. Error: $($_.exception.message)"
            continue
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-output "No Orphaned WIM files found, module clear to run."
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Lol, tad rude Toto.. it does exactly what is asked by the OP. Checks the registry path listed to see if any Wim files are still mounted or orphaned and if found loops through them and Un-mounts them cleanly.